# HTML - Add static row to table with input fields

Tags: php, html

I have a table that looks like this:

```
|  ID  | Weekday | Year | Goal |
|   1  |   31    | 2020 | 220  |
|   2  |   32    | 205  | 220  |
```

Code to display the table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Weekday</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Goal</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>205</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>220</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible (if yes, how?) to add a row at the top of the table(as first row) where  `Weekday`, `Year` and `Goal` has input text and a button, so the user can input value, and submit it to the table?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Weekday</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Goal</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"></td>
    <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>205</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>220</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```